# use tablockx for insert non duplicable data outside a primary key

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, hints

In **SQL Server** I have a table with the following data: *first name, last name, birthplace, etc, etc.*

The table has an identity **ID** column (the primary key of the table). In the interface of my application, the user can modify this data until they hit a button named *"Close Record"*, when this happens I have to generate a **Closed_Record_ID** with syntax ***year + consecutive_number***. For all the records in my table, the order they entered the database (given by the identity **ID**), may not be the same in wich they were closed, so I have to generate a new consecutive number.

How should I use the *Tablockx hint*, or what should I do to avoid duplicate consecutive numbers in the Closed_Record_ID column?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Why not use a [SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)?  You might have to do some data type conversion a couple of times to get the `year + consecutive_number` format you're looking for.  Should work, though.

Comment: On a side note, I would put `year` and `consecutive_number` in separate columns.  It's generally not a good idea to put multiple pieces of data in the same column.

Comment: Thank you for the tip; I'm gonna read about SEQUENCE to see if it fits my needs. And yes, year and consecutive_number are two separate columns